# Hive how to find the position of a pattern in a column

Tags: sql, hive, find, logic

So my data has values like

`':9a:abcd efgh ijkl :12a: mnop qr :52b: stuv w :63a: xyz......'`

How to find the position of each of this tags `:9a:` or `:12a:` or `:52b:` basically I need to find the position of `:??:` (`??` can be anything and they keep changing for every record) the data in between two tags will also change they are fixed length. Please help me if there is a function to find the position of a pattern `:??:` in my data

Comment: `instr(string str, string substr)` See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf

Answer (score 0):

There is [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function in MSSQL Server.

```sql
SELECT position = PATINDEX('%:??:%', 'YOUR:??: STRING');
```

The result is 5 for the example.